# Unicorn.rb, Heroku, Delayed_Job config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, delayed-job, unicorn

I am successfully using Unicorn server and Delayed_Job on Heroku for my site. However I'm unsure if it's setup the best way and am wanted to get more info on how to view worker processes, etc. My config/unicorn.rb file which works is pasted below:

```
worker_processes 3
preload_app true
timeout 30

# setting the below code because of the preload_app true setting above:
# http://unicorn.bogomips.org/Unicorn/Configurator.html#preload_app-method

@delayed_job_pid = nil

before_fork do |server, worker|
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
    Rails.logger.info('Disconnected from ActiveRecord')
    # start the delayed_job worker queue in Unicorn, use " -n 2 " to start 2 workers
    if Rails.env == "production"
      # @delayed_job_pid ||= spawn("RAILS_ENV=production ../script/delayed_job start")
      # @delayed_job_pid ||= spawn("RAILS_ENV=production #{Rails.root.join('script/delayed_job')} start")
      @delayed_job_pid ||= spawn("bundle exec rake jobs:work")
    elsif Rails.env == "development"
      @delayed_job_pid ||= spawn("script/delayed_job start")
      # @delayed_job_pid ||= spawn("rake jobs:work")      
    end

  end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
    Rails.logger.info('Connected to ActiveRecord')
  end
end
```

- delayed_job says to use `RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start` to start worker processes in production mode, but if I use this command I get "file not found" errors in Heroku. So, for now I'm using `bundle exec rake jobs:work` in production, which seems to work, but is this correct?
- How many processes are actually running in this setup and could it be better optimized? My guess is that there is 1 Unicorn master process, 3 Web workers and 1 Delayed job worker for a total of 5? When I run in dev mode locally I see 5 ruby pid's being spawned. Perhaps it would be better to use only 2 Web workers and then give 2 workers to Delayed_job (I have pretty low traffic)
- All of this is run in a single Heroku dyno, so I have no idea how to check the status of the Unicorn workers, any idea how?

**note, I've commented out lines that break the site in production because Heroku says it "can't find the file"

Comment: this posting is helpful but deals with Resque. I'm using delayed_job: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11414321/rails-heroku-unicorn-resque-how-to-choose-the-amount-of-web-workers-resq

Comment: You should run your workers with worker dynos, not your main web dyno: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing

Comment: @ctshryock thank you, i read that article and many others before posting. not sure if you are aware but many people use unicorn web server specifically so that they can spawn multiple web/worker processes within a single dyno. i am not interested in using more than one dyno or I would have just kept using thin server and bought more web workers. if you know about optimizing unicorn and specifically configuring unicorn.rb for heroku though I am all ears. thanks!

Comment: I am aware of the benefits of Unicorn in this context (I also work at Heroku). Don't confuse Unicorn "workers" with background workers. The Unicorn master process forks workers to handle requests. This is all well and good on Heroku. Spawning your own Resque workers within them in this manner, while conceivable, is arguably A Bad Idea. Your dyno should preform a specific unit of work: a web process, or a background process, et. al. If you try to mix them like this you're likely to have a bad time. In this example, if the master process reaps a "web" worker, what happens to the resque worker?

Comment: I meant DJ workers, not Resque workers

Answer (score 3):

Your `config/unicorn.rb` should not spawn a DJ workers like this. You should specify a separate worker process in your `Procfile` like so:

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
worker:  bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

You can use `foreman` for local development to spin up both Unicorn and DJ. Your resulting `config/unicorn.rb` file would then be simpler:

```
worker_processes 3
preload_app true
timeout 30

# setting the below code because of the preload_app true setting above:
# http://unicorn.bogomips.org/Unicorn/Configurator.html#preload_app-method

before_fork do |server, worker|
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
    Rails.logger.info('Disconnected from ActiveRecord')
  end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
    Rails.logger.info('Connected to ActiveRecord')
  end
end
```

As I mentioned in the comments, you're spawning child processes that you never reap, and will likely become zombies. Even if you added code to try and account for that, you're still trying to get single dynos to perform multiple roles (web and background worker), and are likely going to cause you problems down the road (memory errors, et. al).

- Foreman: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile
- DJ on Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job
- Spawn: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Process.html#method-c-spawn

Comment: Does this use a single dyno, or multiple dynos?

Comment: Each process defined in the Procfile will use it's own dyno when scaled. Given the example profile, web=1 worker=0 is 1 dyno running. The one web dyno running Unicorn will itself have 3 worker children, but all contained in the one web process. web=2 and worker=2 is 4 dynos, but 6 unicorn workers.